# Jenkins Pipeline "Branch Specifier" is not evaluating variables

Tags: git, jenkins

Specifying an environment variable for "Branch Specifier" is a documented option, but when I do so, the environment variable doesn't get evaluated. Instead Jenkins shows an error: `Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${GITREF}`

You can see from the screenshot here that the `GITREF` variable appears to be set as intended, but the error message shows that it is not being used to obtain my Jenkinsfile:

[image]

My operation, as I understand it, is:

1. A Github webhook triggers my job.
2. The **Generic Webhook Trigger** plugin sets environment variables from the Github payload.
3. Jenkins should checkout the branch indicated by `$GITREF` but instead uses `$GITREF` as a string literal.

You can see the relevant part of my job config in this screenshot:

[image]

**Do you have any idea what I need to change?** Any new branch on my git repo may hold changes to the Jenkinsfile, so I want my pipeline configuration to get its Jenkinsfile from whatever branch triggered the current build.

Here's the help text related to using a variable on this config item:

[image]

Comment: You will find an option named `Lightweight checkout` below `Branches to build` section. Try disabling it and then run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling `Lightweight checkout` option present below `Branches to build` section. We also use variable in our jobs in `Branches to build` section and have disabled `Lightweight checkout` option long time ago when we faced the same issue.

There was an issue posted [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/564) which described similar behaviour. Lightweight checkout has issue but full checkout works just fine.

Comment: worked for me.. after disabling lightweight checkout